# Service Bus Component of Azure on Premise data gateway - Pricing

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, data-gateway

according to MS there is a Azure Service bus component to on-prem data gateway , however when you install the Azure component no service bus resource created. we need to understand the impact on pricing i.e. is the price of service bus hidden within Azure on prem data gateway ? there is no pricing guidelines for Azure On premise gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a licensing cost for the data gateway and data flowing into Azure is free. You pay egress costs which can be calculated using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/

Answer (score 1):

The On-premises data gateway relies on Azure Service Bus for cloud connectivity and correspondingly establishes outbound connections to its associated Azure region, which means an Azure Service Bus implicitly created when a data gateway is installed.

Created Azure Service Bus will not be shown explicitly. There is no extra cost for it. All you have to pay is for the on-prem data gateway which includes all infrastructure costs(Azure Service Bus).

Comment: Hi there , when you say "all you need is to pay for on prem data gateway" , do you mean the Azure resource ? I have looked at Azure pricing and there is no pricing guidelines for on prem data gateway.

Comment: Hi, every service you use in Azure has a cost. But unfortunately I too found no pricing guidelines for on prem data gateway.

Comment: Has anyone found pricing guidance for an the Data Gateway yet?